# Create dataframe from text file with {} in it

Tags: dataframe

I want to make a dataframe out of the following text file:

{"1":5,"2":5,"4a":5,"4b":5,"4c":5,"4d":5,"4e":5}

In such a way that it will look like this:

[image]

Can you help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
  df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f),index=[0])
print(df)
```

output

```
   1  2  4a  4b  4c  4d  4e
0  5  5   5   5   5   5   5
```

Comment: Thanks I was not familiar with Json files, this helped me out!